# Scanf on nasm assembly program

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I am trying to write a simple program using `scanf` and `printf`, but it is not storing my values properly.

```
        extern printf
        extern scanf

        SECTION .data
  str1: db "Enter a number: ",0,10
  str2: db "your value is %d, squared = %d",0,10
  fmt1: db "%d",0
  location: dw 0h


        SECTION .bss
  input1: resw 1 

        SECTION .text
        global main

   main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        push str1
        call printf 
        add esp, 4

        push location
        push fmt1 
        call scanf
        mov ebx, eax            ;ebx holds input

        mul eax                 ;eax holds input*input

        push eax
        push ebx
        push dword str2
        call printf
        add esp, 12

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        mov eax,0
        ret
```

For some reason when I run the program, no matter what number I enter, the program prints 1 for both inputs.

I am using nasm, linked with gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making an incorrect assumption here:

```
call scanf
mov ebx, eax            ;ebx holds input
```

`scanf` actually returns *"the number of items of the argument list successfully filled"* ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)). Your integer is in `location`.
By the way, you should probably make `location` at least 4 bytes (i.e. use `dd` instead of `dw`).

Comment: Also, calling convention mandates that `ebx` should be preserved. You might want to use `ecx` instead. Furthermore there is a missing `add esp, 8` after the `call scanf`, but that's harmless in this case because you restore the stack pointer from `ebp`.